# GridView becomes NULL after sorting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I run this event-handler and method to sort my GridView, but it says that GridView is null:

```
protected void OtherGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtSortTable = gvMeldingen.DataSource as DataTable;
        
            DataView dvSortedView = new DataView(dtSortTable);
            dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString(e.SortDirection);
            gvMeldingen.DataSource = dvSortedView;
            gvMeldingen.DataBind();
        
    }
    private string getSortDirectionString(SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        string newSortDirection = String.Empty;
        if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            newSortDirection = "ASC";
        }
        else
        {
            newSortDirection = "DESC";
        }
        return newSortDirection;
    }
```

The error I get: DataTable must be set prior to using DataView.

And this highlighted: `dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString(e.SortDirection)`

Comment: Is dtSortaTable null ? Could you please post the code in the Load event of the page ?

Comment: i get this error: DataTable must be set prior to using DataView.

and this highlighted: dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString(e.SortDirection);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataSource property is lost during roundtrips. That's why `DataTable dtSortTable = gvMeldingen.DataSource as DataTable;` is null, and `DataView dvSortedView = new DataView(dtSortTable);` is invalid.

When you hit a sort hyperlink on a datagrid, you are triggering a postback from the client to the server. Then ASP.NET constructs the reply page using persisted data like the ViewState and others.

The *DataSource* property is not part of the persisted state between round trip, that's why its value is lost.

A solution is requery your DataSource as below:

```
protected void OtherGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        var SortExpression = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString(e.SortDirection);

        gvMeldingen.DataSource = ... // Requery the Data using the new sort expression above
        gvMeldingen.DataBind();
    }
```

Another solution is to set the DataSource each time in the Page_Load event (not recommended)

Comment: this gives errors look at where you assign something directly to the type SortExpression.

Comment: and what about the datasource of gvMeldingen?

Comment: About the DataSource of gvMeldingen, can you please post the piece of code where it is populated the first time ?

Comment: the datasource gets data from a database but i work with tabs and every tab should change the datasource at the WHERE statement. The first tab does nothing, so the WHERE statement changes when clicking the second tab.

Comment: What about creating a Populate() method in where you populate your datasource ( .DataSource = ...; DataBind(); ), and you keep WHERE and ORDER BY statement in some variables elsewhere (keep both using the viewstate). Then, you call this Populate() after each tab change or sort click.

Answer (score 0):

As you are putting a `DataView` around the `DataTable`, the method will only work the first time (assuming that the data source is a `DataTable` from start). The next time the data source is a `DataView`, and you can't cast it to `DataTable`.

Use the default view of the `DataTable` as data source from start, so that the data source is always a `DataView`. Then you can get the view from the source, and get the underlying table from that:

```
DataView view = gvMeldingen.DataSource as DataView;
DataTable dtSortTable = view.Table;
```

Comment: I am not sure if DataSource is persisted between round trips

Comment: this is the error I get after your code: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: this part is highlighted: DataTable dtSortTable = view.Table;

Comment: @Laurent: Yes, you are right, the data source is of course recreated on each postback.

Comment: @Tassisto: Then your data source is neither a `DataTable` nor a `DataView`. You have to check in your code what you put in the data source so that you know how to use it.